# How to configure native vlan on D-Links switches

Tags: vlan, trunk

My infrastructure contains exclusively D-Link switches, I wonder if there is a way to configure native vlan on trunk ports?

I need to configure native on DGS-3100 48

Comment: It will depend on the device model. Not all the D-Link switches support VLAN.

Comment: it is DGS-3100 48 Port switch.

Comment: I think native vlan is just a Cisco term. A native vlan is simply a vlan that is untagged on a trunk port. Usually Cisco require this because management packets such as for spanning tree will need to be send without vlan tagging. Hope this helps,

Comment: If you have a switch that does not support dot1q and it is connected to a switch that does support dot1q, you can configure a native vlan on the trunk port of the second switch, to force him tag the incoming frames with a native vlan id.
I am connecting hosts and switches to the same ports, when a host is connected it should be and access port, when a switch is connected it should be a trunk port, because I can not disable dot1q on my access layer switches, so configuring native vlan on the trunk port of my distribution layer switch will solve my problem.

Comment: Frames are only tagged with VLAN numbers on trunks. Any untagged frames on a trunk are in the native VLAN for that trunk. Each trunk could have a different native VLAN. Frames coming into access ports are not tagged with VLAN numbers, unless the frames exit the switch on a trunk where the VLAN number for access port they came in is not the native VLAN of the trunk.

Comment: the question is how to configure a native vlan on dlink 3100

Comment: why change it ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DGS-3100 series supports IEEE 802.1Q VLANs.

The switch's default is to assign all ports to a single 802.1Q VLAN named *default.*
The *default* VLAN has a VID = 1.

If a port is configured with *Tagging* enabled, then incoming frames that come with a tag will be untouched and will maintain its VID, but if they come untagged then it will put a VID number.

This port will be a "trunk port" (capable of receiving tagged traffic from one or more VLANs).

For more details, here is the configuration [manual](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/338963/dgs310048.pdf)  (**Tagging and untagging**, page 68).

Comment: my question is about native vlans, what you just described is the basic vlan principles, I need to know does my switch support native vlans, and if yes, then how can I configure it.
Thanks.

Comment: tagged(trunk) ports can tag untagged(ethernet) incoming frames with a single vlan id called native vlan.

Comment: @EdikMkoyan Check the part where I say: `but if they come untagged then it will put a VID number`. I think that's is the key to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly a port can only be a member of one untagged VLAN. Dlink however has a feature documented in the manual called "Asymetric VLAN" that allows multiple VLANS to be untagged on the same port. This allows multipple VLANS to access the same server but not eachother. This feature needs to be enabled for it to be possible to untag multipple VLANS on the same port. From the manual:

Port 1 connect to Server; port 1, port 3, port 9 and port 17 are untagged ports; PC3 & PC4 are in the same VLAN#3; port 1 
is  a  untagged  member  of  VLAN#2  and  VLAN#3  (untagged  member  overlap).  Then  the  server  can  talk  with  VLAN#2,
VLAN#3; PC3 and PC4 can talk to the server and to each ot
her; PC2 can talk to the Se
rver; VLAN#2 can’t communicate 
with VLAN3. 
In this example port 1 need to be untagged member in VLAN#2 & VLAN#3, so Asymmetric VLAN should be enabled